# If value of first array is found on second array, replace and echo it

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

```
$array1 = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth');
$array2 = array('second' => 'bye', 'first' => 'hello',  'third' => 'see you', 'fifth' => 'good evening');
```

and I echo the content of `$array1` like

```
foreach ($array1 as $extra) {
echo $extra; }
```

What I am trying to do is to check every time before echoing the `$extra` whether the output is found in `$array2`. And if yes, to echo the value of the `array2` instead.

So in my example above, instead of `first second third fourth` I want to echo `hello bye see you fourth`.

How can I do this?

Comment: `if (isset($array2[ $extra ])) { .. /* exist */ ..}`

Answer (score 2):

You can access `$array2[$key]` and use the [null-coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) since you apparently want to fall back to the value from `$array1` if it doesn't exist as a key in `$array2`.

```
foreach ($array1 as $key) {
  echo $array2[$key] ?? $key, ' ';
  // [PHP5] echo isset($array2[$key]) ? $array2[$key] : $key, ' ';
}
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/3vQYt**

Note: this adds a potentially unwanted space at the end. If that's the case, either add a condition to the loop or do something like this instead:

```
echo implode(' ', array_map(function ($key) use ($array2) { 
  return $array2[$key] ?? $key;
  // [PHP5] return isset($array2[$key]) ? $array2[$key] : $key;
}, $array1));
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/VCDVt**

Comment: Hello, thank you for this, can you please help me on writing it to php 5.6 instead of 7?

Comment: Thanks again. One last question, I just noticed that the array I explode is like this `array(23) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "ABS"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "ESP"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Airbag 6"` is this structure something that the code can not handle?

Comment: @EnexoOnoma You mean `$array1` or `$array2`? If it's your `$array1` then it's perfectly fine, if it's your `$array2` then the values from `$array1` need to be these numeric indexes themselves. You can use https://3v4l.org/ to show me an example if you'd like.

Comment: the above sample array is my `array1` and is exploded from a string like `ABS,ESP,Airbag 6`. the format oft he `array2` is like the one I posted in the question. Unfortunately i can't make it work though

Comment: hey I made it work! thank you for your help and guidance!

Comment: @EnexoOnoma You're welcome! If you can, mark one of the answers as accepted (green tick on its left).

Comment: @EnexoOnoma *the above sample array is my array1 and is exploded from a string like ABS,ESP,Airbag 6*. You should have included that in the question. It's always better to keep the question as "far back" as possible when you have not done any processing to the input. That makes it easier to us to find the optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
$array1 = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth');
$array2 = array('second' => 'bye', 'first' => 'hello',  'third' => 'see you', 'fifth' => 'good evening');
print_r(array_intersect_key( $array2 ,array_flip($array1)));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [second] => bye
    [first] => hello
    [third] => see you
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/70f4a1489aa1dc8fa8d0bb1ff5b0fcf3babbded7)

> **array_intersect_key()** returns an array containing all the entries of array1 which have keys that are present in all the arguments. 
>   https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

And

> **array_flip()** returns an array in flip order, i.e. keys from array become values and values from array become keys. 
>   https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

**Update**

> I know but it's array1 that is the "string". Array2 is the replacements. See the question: I want to echo hello bye see you fourth

```
$array1 = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth');
$array2 = array('second' => 'bye', 'first' => 'hello',  'third' => 'see you', 'fifth' => 'good evening');

echo implode(' ', array_intersect_key( array_merge(array_combine($array1,$array1), $array2) ,array_flip($array1)));
```

Output

```
hello bye see you fourth
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd93d06209f78387bfad4796c822d8cb14a86335)

The difference with this one is this bit

```
 $array2 = array_merge(array_combine($array1,$array1), $array2)
```

What this does is make a new array with `array_combine` which has the same keys as values.  In this case:

```
array('first'=>'first', 'second'=>'second', 'third'=>'third',  'fourth'=>'fourth')
```

Then we use the fact that when merging 2 rows the second array will overwrite keys from the first so we merge that with our original `$array2`

```
$array2 = array('second' => 'bye', 'first' => 'hello',  'third' => 'see you', 'fourth'=>'fourth', 'fifth' => 'good evening');
```

So by doing this "extra" step we insure that all elements in `$array1` exist in `$array2` - the order of `$array1` is also preserved - in this case it just adds `'fourth'=>'fourth'` but that is exactly what we need for the intersect to work.

Then we just implode it.

**UPDATE2**

This is a simpler one using `preg_filter` and `preg_replace`

```
$array1 = array('first', 'second', 'third',  'fourth');
$array2 = array('second' => 'bye', 'first' => 'hello',  'third' => 'see you', 'fifth' => 'good evening');

echo implode(' ',preg_replace(preg_filter('/(.+)/', '/(\1)/i', array_keys($array2)), $array2, $array1));
```

Output

```
hello bye see you fourth
```

It's very similar to the `str_replace` one, so I didn't want to post it as it's own answer.  But it does have a few benefits over `str_replace`.  For example

```
echo implode(' ',preg_replace(preg_filter('/(.+)/', '/\b(\1)\b/i', array_keys($array2)), $array2, $array1));
```

Now we have `\b` word boundaries, which means `first` wont match `firstone` etc.

Sorry I really enjoy doing things like this, it's "fun" for me.

Comment: There is no `fourth`

Comment: @Andreas - there is no forth in `$array2` either.  You can't output something that doesn't exist.

Comment: I know but it's array1 that is the "string". Array2 is the replacements. See the question: *I want to echo `hello bye see you fourth`*

Comment: Ok, I can fix that and keep it one line :)

Comment: I'm not so sure you can :-) I thought about a solution like this before. Mind the overhead looping in the background

Comment: To compile? :-) couldn't resist. There is lots of loops in the background there. It's a short code but in the background there is lots of stuff going on.

Comment: I doubt you would notice, especially on a tiny array.  Maybe it's a pico second slower.  It's less easy to read... now.  Give the Junior developers something to scratch their heads over.... ha ha.  I have long sense gotten bored of `foreach`

Comment: Good one! +1 from me. Agree that Preg_replace is better, I went to bed before Jeto posted the comment to my answer so I couldn't fix the problem "in time".

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array1 as $extra) {
      foreach ($array2 as $key=>$value) {
          if($extra==$key){
               echo $value;
          }
      }
}
```

something like this

Answer (score 1):

Just use `isset`:

```
foreach($array1 as $e) {
    $val = isset($array2[$e]) ? $array2[$e] : $e;
    echo $val;
}
```

Doc can be found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 1):

You can just implode the first array then use str_replace to replace the words from the second in the imploded string.
No need for loops in my opinion.

```
echo str_replace(array_keys($array2), $array2, implode(" ", $array1));
//hello bye see you fourth
```

Array_keys will take the keys from array2 and make them the find, then the values from array2 will be the replacements.

https://3v4l.org/UIWV0

Comment: Doesn't work if keys have the same substrings in them. E.g. if you replace `first` with `firstsecond`.

Comment: @Jeto True. There are limits with str_replace.